# subfloat - issues with the subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, alignment

I am new at LaTeX and I have been some problems with the subcaption text, since I have to put five images in a singe row. I have the follow code for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Standart Reification]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subfloat[Named Graphs]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[n-ary  Relations]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \subfloat[Singleton Properties]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subfloat[NdFluents]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{RDF Approaches}
  \label{fig:subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And my output image, have been looking like this:
[image: output]

The first four subcaptions has a weird alignment. How can I resolve this alignment problem, making the subcaptions looking like the last subcaption?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh, really sorry, from now my code is compiling. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: The first four sub-captions are simply too long to fit in 1/5 of `\textwidth`. P.S. Your code is still not compilable to us because we don’t have your image files `.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the alignment of the sub-captions by [explicitly setting the alignment](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf#subsection.3.1) for the sub-captions.

`\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,justification=raggedright}`

If you really want the captions all in one line, you would have to change the fontsize.

With the more recent [`subcaption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package and it's provided `subfigure` this would look like:

### Result

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang,justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
 \caption{Standart Reification}
 \label{fig:ExampleA}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
 \caption{Named Graphs}
 \label{fig:ExampleB}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
 \caption{n-ary  Relations}
 \label{fig:ExampleC}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Singleton Properties}
\label{fig:ExampleD}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
 \caption{NDFlunents}
 \label{fig:ExampleE}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{RDF Approaches}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```